# Autenticacion con Laravel y JWT

Tags: laravel, jwt

Yo implemente JWT con laravel de manera correcta y uso postman para ver el token que me retorna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y despues se supone que con ese token se hace un Bearer y este te permite acceder a ciertas rutas por el middlewere de JWT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es como utilizo ese bearer para poder acceder a todas las rutas, yo coloco el bearer de forma manual en la ruta y me deja ver todas las vistas pero esa no es la idea la idea es que este se almacene internamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que estas utilizando para el frontend, el mismo laravel o algún framework o librería de js? En cualquiera de los dos casos igualmente necesitas crear un middleware que valide que la petición cuenta con un token JWT, validando su expiracion así como su correcta estructura.

Comment: solo uso el laravel, pero el jwt ya tiene su middleware el problema es que si arriba por get no le paso el bearer no me deja acceder a los sitios.